# sql query to find the get the sum of difference in datetime stamps in hours

Tags: sql-server, datetime, calculated-columns

I am trying to achieve single views on the given table:

```
Table:LeaseLog
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
action           license           timeStamp
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lease            ----YYB--------            2014-07-18 14:30:36.000 <br/>
Release          --YYB--------          2014-07-18 15:17:11.000 <br/>
Lease            ----AAR--------            2014-07-18 14:40:23.000 <br/>
Release          ---AAR -------     2014-07-18 15:38:41.000 <br/>
Lease            ---AAR----------           2014-07-18 15:41:16.000 <br/>
Lease            ---YYB----------           2014-07-19 07:53:06.000 <br/>
Release          ----YYB------          2014-07-19 08:07:51.000 <br/>
Lease            ----YYB---------           2014-07-19 08:12:43.000 <br/>
Release          ----AAR------          2014-07-19 08:19:59.000 <br/>
```

The goal is to find the license utilization for every used licenses in hours or minutes between lease and release timeStamp. 
i For each license key:Iterate through lease and release: ConvertIntoHours(LeaseTimeStamp - ReleaseTimeStamp)
ii) Sum(the result of i) group by license

The output should get like this:

```
license                   TotalUtilzation(Hours)
----------------------------------------------
YYB     ---------                  160.20 <br/>
AAR   ----------                   380    <br/>
```

I was manage to write the script that will give the total hours for lease and release for given datetime using the below script

```
SELECT x.license, 
SUM(CASE WHEN action='lease' THEN ((DATEPART(hh,timeStamp)*60)+DATEPART(mi,timeStamp)+(DATEPART(ss,timeStamp)/(60.0))) ELSE 0 END)/60.0  as Lease,
SUM(CASE WHEN action='release'THEN ((DATEPART(hh,timeStamp)*60)+DATEPART(mi,timeStamp)+(DATEPART(ss,timeStamp)/(60.0))) ELSE 0 END)/60.0 as Release
FROM [RxDatabase].[dbo].[LeaseLog]AS x
GROUP BY license
```

And I know this is not giving the correct result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

because you need to make calculations between 2 different **ROWS** you need to use the **OVER** keyword

a great post can be found here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

**in short:**

1. ordeer your table rows so each Lease record will have Release record right next to it
2. apply OVER
3. apply the original calculation you made

### EDIT:

a very basic demonstration for a difference between lease and release date for a specific vehicle

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(hour, leaseTime, releaseTime) AS diff
FROM
(
    SELECT x.license, x.action, x.timeStamp as leaseTime
    LEAD (x.timeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY x.timeStamp) releaseTime 
    FROM [RxDatabase].[dbo].[LeaseLog] AS x
    WHERE x.license = '----YYB--------'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I am still wondering why would we need to use OVER to find the previous and next of time stamp, while the subsequent record itself will be on lease, release if we query per license keys..The question is still how would we manage to find the difference on those 2-1, 4-3, 6-5....records

Comment: Also for LEAD (x.timeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY x.action) releaseTime  is not the release time when ordered by action.